# How to call a method with List< string> parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, list, select, methods

I just try to learn C# as a beginner (and my english ist poor, sry)
I want to read a mySQL Database
I found a very good article about that in

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL

I succeed for example in calling the method count by

```
        DBConnect dbx = new DBConnect();
        int i2 = dbx.Count();
```

but question: how to call the method Select
it is defined by :

```
        public List< string >[] Select()
```

**How to declare a List in my main-program and call the method?**

I tried code like

```
List<Daten> liste = new List<Daten>();
liste = dbx.Select()[myDaten];
```

for simplicity, assume in "Daten" i have only 2 variables "name" as string and "age" as integer

Comment: List<string> list = Select ();

or you can use keyword var instead of specific type

    var list = Select ();

Comment: i solved it with "var list". thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the article mentioned this method:

```
public List< string >[] Select()
```

Is just a part of **DBConnect** class. So to get data you have to call dbx.Select(); to get data only. If you want to transform your data into class **Daten** you have to update the code for Select method to return a collection of Daten class instances instead of collection of strings.
Code would look approximately like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Daten> Select()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tableinfo";

    //Create a list to store the result
    List<Daten>list = new List<Daten>();

    //Open connection
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        //Create Command
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        //Create a data reader and Execute the command
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Read the data and store them in the list
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            var id = int.Parse(dataReader["id"]);
            var name = dataReader["name"];
            var age = int.Parse(dataReader["age"]);

            var daten = new Daten { Id = id, Age = age, Name = name };
            list.Add(daten)
        }

        //close Data Reader
        dataReader.Close();

        //close Connection
        this.CloseConnection();

        //return list to be displayed
        return list;
    }
    else
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Here I assume, that Daten class looks like this:

```
public class Daten {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I solved it with the comment of Valentin and var list. In your examle i did not get the statement " var daten = new Daten { Id = id, Age = age, Name = name };" running.

Comment: i solved it with the comment of Valentin. In your example i did not get the statement " var daten = new Daten { Id = id, Age = age, Name = name };" running. Nevertheless, I will check it later, maybe for future things it may be the better way ! Thanks (by the way, how can i edt my question to mark ist [SOLVED]

Comment: var daten = new Daten { Id = id, Age = age, Name = name }; to get this statement running you have to define class Daten like I defined it in the lower code block. Also I forgot to add type conversion for the data that comes from DB, updated the code, Keep in mind that it will work only if Id and Age are not nullable in DB